# Theano: where to input " theano-cache clear"

Tags: theano

To remove theano compile cache, Theano 0.9 document says using 'theano-cache clear'.

I don't know where to type the command. I am using anaconda with spyder. Does the command should be input in anaconda prompt, spyder console or cmd?

Typing the command in anaconda prompt yields the error message:

```
'theano-cache' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there other way in addition to the command to remove the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I also met this error, I delete it in the folder: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Theano` (maybe I am wrong). But in this way I didn't solve other problems later. I used `pip install theano==0.8.2` to install an other version, and installed `CUDA7.5`, then it worked. My system is Windows 8.1, and my GPU is 830M.

Anyways, I found it is easy to install theano in linux, I have installed it in Ubuntu 16.04.

I hope it can help you.